# Keras input shape error

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, neural-network, keras

I'm new to Keras and I am trying to create my network which needs to learn on a card game. It takes 93 binary inputs with a hidden layer with 40 neurons and a single output neuron which computes a score (from 0 to 25).

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(input_dim=93, units=40, activation="sigmoid"))
model.add(Dense(units=2, activation="linear"))
sgd = optimizers.SGD(lr=0.01, clipvalue=0.5)
model.compile(loss="mse", optimizer=sgd, learning_rate=0.01)
```

I'm trying first to compute (do a forward propagation) of the 93 inputs

this is "s.toInputs()"

> [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 1
>    1 1 0 1 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0
>    0 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 1]

```
model.predict(np.array(s.toInputs())
```

but i get the error

> ValueError: Error when checking : expected dense_1_input to have shape (None, 93) but got array with shape (93, 1)

How do I pass the correct parameters?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually `s.toInputs()` should look like this

> [[0,0,0, etc...],[0,1,0, etc...]]

Basically you have to have an array with the following shape: (`n_batches`, `n_attributes`)

You have 93 attributes so this should do the trick if you are using tensorflow

```
np.array(s.toInputs()).reshape(-1, 93)
```

**Fully working example**

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(input_dim=93, units=40, activation="sigmoid"))
model.add(Dense(units=2, activation="linear"))
sgd = optimizers.SGD(lr=0.01, clipvalue=0.5)
model.compile(loss="mse", optimizer=sgd, learning_rate=0.01)

# random data
n_batches = 10
data = np.random.randint(0,2,93*n_batches)
data = data.reshape(-1,93)

model.predict(data)
```

Answer (score 1):

The error message tells you, that your data needs to have the shape `(None, 93)` (`None`here means, this dimension can have an arbitrary value. It is the number of your samples)

But your input data has the shape `(93,1)`. Note that the dimensions are reversed.
You can use transpose to get your data in the right shape:

```
model.predict(np.array(s.toInputs()).T)
```

Answer (score -1):

The reshaping thing works well.
Reshape the array to (batch_size, your_input_dimensions)

np.reshape(batch_size, input_dimesions)